# OrientDB - how to disable transaction?

Tags: orientdb

sorry for so simple question, but how to disable transaction in OrientDB? Maybe it can do used by OrientDB studio or sql query, anything, thanks.

Comment: Could you explain better your question, please ?

Comment: Disable transaction or display it?

Comment: Disable transaction, see this link [link]https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/3763

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use document DB transactions are already disabled by default.

If you use graph DB you shoul call

`com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientTransactionalGraph#setAutoStartTx`

with false.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to this link: **http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Graph-Consistency.html**

Since v2.1.7, OrientDB provides a new mode to manage graphs without using transactions. It uses the Java class OrientGraphNoTx or via SQL by changing the global setting sql.graphConsistencyMode to one of the following values:

- tx

the default, uses transactions to maintain consistency. This was the only available setting before v2.1.7

- notx_sync_repair

avoids the use of transactions. Consistency, in case of a JVM crash, is guaranteed through a database repair operation, which runs at startup in synchronous mode. The database cannot be used until the repair is finished.

- notx_async_repair

also avoids the use of transactions. Consistency, in case of JVM crash, is guaranteed through a database repair operation, which runs at startup in asynchronous mode. The database can be used immediately, as the repair procedure will run in the background.